# Syntax error in lex yacc

Tags: yacc, lex

here is my lex yacc code to parse an XML file and print the contents between  and  tags.

LEX

```
%{

%}
%%
"<XML>" {return XMLSTART;}
"</XML>" {return XMLEND;}
[a-z]+ {yylval=strdup(yytext); return TEXT;}
"<" {yylval=strdup(yytext);return yytext[0];}
">" {yylval=strdup(yytext);return yytext[0];}
"\n" {yylval=strdup(yytext);return yytext[0];}
. {}
%%
```

YACC

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define YYSTYPE char *
%}
%token XMLSTART
%token XMLEND
%token TEXT
%%
program : XMLSTART '\n' A '\n' XMLEND {printf("%s",$3);
                                        }
A : '<' TEXT '>' '\n' A '\n' '<' TEXT '>'  { $$ = strcat($1,strcat($2,strcat($3,strcat($4,strcat($5,strcat($6,strcat($7,strcat($8,$9))))))));}
  | TEXT
%%
#include"lex.yy.c"
```

I'm getting Syntax error, tried using ECHOs at some places but didn't find the error.
The input file I'm using is:

```
<XML>
<hello>
hi
<hello>
</XML>
```

Please help me figure out the error. I have relatively less experience using lex and yacc

Comment: See my grammar. You must be referring to the closing tag of hello. But my grammar treats closing tags as <TEXT>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That grammar will only successfully parse a file which has `XMLEND` at the end. However, all text files end with a newline.
2. Although you could presumably fix that by adding a newline at the end of the start rule, it's almost always a bad idea to try to parse whitespace. In general, except for line-oriented languages -- which xml is not -- it is best to ignore whitespace.
3. Your use of `strcat` is incorrect. Quoting `man strcat` from a GNU/Linux system:

   > The  `strcat()`  function  appends  the src string to the dest string, overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of dest, and then adds a terminating null byte.  The strings may not overlap, and **the dest string must have enough space for the result.**  If  dest  is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable; buffer overruns are a favorite avenue for attacking secure programs.

   You might want to use `asprintf` if it exists in your standard library.
4. Also, you never `free()` the strings produced by `strdup`, so all of them leak memory. In general, it's better to not set `strdup` tokens whose string representation is known -- particularly single-character tokens -- but the important thing is to keep track of the tokens whose string value has been freshly allocated. That would apply to semantic values produced with `asprintf` if the above suggestion is taken.

Comment: replaced strcat with sprintf, and removed strdup for single character strings. appended new line to the start production for now. And voila! it worked. need to improove it now